# How to manipulate specific SVG Paths in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, path

I am extremely new to D3, so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question. I have in my HTML document a set of paths that form water basins around the US, and I'm trying to zoom in and move specific paths whenever they are clicked. The SVG itself was provided to me by my client, and was not created using D3.

Here's an example of the path for the Ohio River Basin:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Basins_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 256.1 128.9" style="position:absolute; top:-140px; left:-27px; opacity:0.8;" width="920" height="700" enable-background="new 0 0 256.1 128.9" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st" id="ohio_3_" fill="#A1A6D0" stroke="#2D2A2B" stroke-width="0.1045" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M209.6,85.3l-1.8-1.4l-1.9-3.2l-0.6-3.6l1.3-3.7c0.8-0.4,1.3-1.1,1.5-1.9c0.3-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.1c-0.6-0.9-0.3-2-0.5-3
    c-0.1-0.7,0.3-1.2,0.5-1.8c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-0.9c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.6,0.4-1.1c0-0.7,0.2-1.4,0.1-2.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7
    c-0.3-0.9-0.3-0.9,0.4-0.9c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.2,0.3c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.3,1.2-0.7c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3c0.2-0.6,0.1-1.3,1-1.4
    c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.4-0.3,1,0,1.3-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.2c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3,0.1l0,0c0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.8
    c0,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.3,2,0.4h0c0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.2c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.7
    c0.4-0.8,1.1-0.4,1.7-0.3c0.7,0.2,0.9-0.5,1.3-0.8c0.4-0.2,1.1-0.1,0.9-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.3-0.2,0.7,0,1.1-0.2
    c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c0.6-0.1,1-0.7,1.6-0.7c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.3c0.5,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.7-0.5c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.8,0.3-1
    c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.4,0.2,0.7,0,0.7-0.5c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.5-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.1-1.3v0
    c0.3-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3l0,0c0.5-0.2,0.9-0.6,1.1-1.1l0,0c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.5,1.1-0.6h0.1c0.5,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.5-0.2
    c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.1l0,0c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.7l0,0c0.5,0.6,1.2,0.9,1.6,1.6c0,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.9c-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.9-1,1.6
    c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.4-0.4,2.1c-0.2,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.4,1.1c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,1c-0.1,1-0.7,1.9-0.6,2.9c0.1,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.1
    c-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.8-0.6,1.3c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.5,1.2c-0.3,0.9-0.7,1.8-1,2.7
    c-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.7-0.5,1.1c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6c-0.2,0.3-0.1,0.8-0.4,1.1l0,0c-0.3,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.3,1.3c0,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5
    c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.4,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.7c-0.4,0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.8-0.9,0.9l0,0
    c-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.6-1.1,1c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-2.1,2.5c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.4,0.5,0,1.2-0.4,1.8l0,0c-0.4,0.2-0.5,0.7-0.9,0.9
    c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.5-0.5-1-0.3-1.2,0.3h0c-0.3,0.1-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.6l-0.1,0h-0.1c-0.2,0-0.6-0.3-0.5,0.3l0,0.1
    c0,0.7-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0-0.5-0.2c-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8-1.2-0.9c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5
    c-0.8-0.1-0.4,0.7-0.7,1c-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8,0.6c-0.5,0.1-1,0.4-1.3,0.9c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7
    c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.4,0.1-0.7-0.2-1.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.1-0.1
    c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.2c-0.3-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.1-0.5c-0.5-0.2-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.8,0.2-1.4-0.3-2-0.6
    c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.7-0.9L209.6,85.3z"/>
```

I have been trying to manipulate this path in order to shift and "zoom in" on the specific water basin whenever the user clicks on it, but things are proving much more difficult than I expected. So I'm wondering if it's impossible to manipulate specific paths in an SVG using D3, or if I need to have created the SVG in D3 to work with it? Any help will be much appreciated.

(Also, this is my first forum post, so I apologize in advance for poor wording).

Comment: shifting and zooming are normally implemented using transforms. You can apply a transform to a pre-existing path in d3 if you select it. Reading some d3 tutorials is likely to be useful at this point if you are just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want panning and zooming on the shape, `d3` makes it pretty simple to add it (even to an existing path).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Basins_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 256.1 128.9" style="position:absolute; top:-140px; left:-27px; opacity:0.8;" width="920" height="700" enable-background="new 0 0 256.1 128.9"
  xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="st" id="ohio_3_" fill="#A1A6D0" stroke="#2D2A2B" stroke-width="0.1045" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M209.6,85.3l-1.8-1.4l-1.9-3.2l-0.6-3.6l1.3-3.7c0.8-0.4,1.3-1.1,1.5-1.9c0.3-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.1c-0.6-0.9-0.3-2-0.5-3
    c-0.1-0.7,0.3-1.2,0.5-1.8c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-0.9c0.4-0.3,0.7-0.6,0.4-1.1c0-0.7,0.2-1.4,0.1-2.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7
    c-0.3-0.9-0.3-0.9,0.4-0.9c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.4,1.2,0.3c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.3,1.2-0.7c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3c0.2-0.6,0.1-1.3,1-1.4
    c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1c0.4-0.3,1,0,1.3-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.2c0.8,0,1.6-0.2,2.3,0.1l0,0c0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.8
    c0,0.5,0.3,0.9,0.6,1.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.3,2,0.4h0c0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.2c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.7
    c0.4-0.8,1.1-0.4,1.7-0.3c0.7,0.2,0.9-0.5,1.3-0.8c0.4-0.2,1.1-0.1,0.9-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.3-0.2,0.7,0,1.1-0.2
    c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c0.6-0.1,1-0.7,1.6-0.7c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.3c0.5,0.3,0.7,0.1,0.7-0.5c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.8,0.3-1
    c0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c0.4,0.2,0.7,0,0.7-0.5c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.5-0.4,0.9-0.7,1.1-1.3v0
    c0.3-0.5,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.3l0,0c0.5-0.2,0.9-0.6,1.1-1.1l0,0c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.5,1.1-0.6h0.1c0.5,0.3,1.1,0.7,1.5-0.2
    c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.1l0,0c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.7,0.7l0,0c0.5,0.6,1.2,0.9,1.6,1.6c0,0.5-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.9c-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.9-1,1.6
    c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.4-0.4,2.1c-0.2,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.4,1.1c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.7,1c-0.1,1-0.7,1.9-0.6,2.9c0.1,0.5-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.1
    c-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.8-0.6,1.3c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.5,1.2c-0.3,0.9-0.7,1.8-1,2.7
    c-0.1,0.4-0.4,0.7-0.5,1.1c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.6c-0.2,0.3-0.1,0.8-0.4,1.1l0,0c-0.3,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.3,1.3c0,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.5
    c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.4,0.3c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.7c-0.4,0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.2c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3c-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.8-0.9,0.9l0,0
    c-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.6-1.1,1c-1,0.6-1.6,1.6-2.1,2.5c0,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3c-0.4,0.5,0,1.2-0.4,1.8l0,0c-0.4,0.2-0.5,0.7-0.9,0.9
    c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1c-0.5-0.5-1-0.3-1.2,0.3h0c-0.3,0.1-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.6l-0.1,0h-0.1c-0.2,0-0.6-0.3-0.5,0.3l0,0.1
    c0,0.7-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0-0.5-0.2c-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.8-1.2-0.9c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5
    c-0.8-0.1-0.4,0.7-0.7,1c-0.1,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8,0.6c-0.5,0.1-1,0.4-1.3,0.9c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7
    c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.4,0.1-0.7-0.2-1.1-0.1c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.1-0.1
    c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.8,0.2c-0.3-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.1-0.5c-0.5-0.2-0.7,0.1-0.9,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2c-0.8,0.2-1.4-0.3-2-0.6
    c-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2c-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.8-0.7-0.9L209.6,85.3z"></path>

    <script>
      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        path = svg.select("path"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

      var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 40])
        .translateExtent([
          [-100, -100],
          [width, height]
        ])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

      svg.call(zoom);

      function zoomed() {
        path.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
      }

    </script>
  </svg>
</body>

</html
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks so much for your help. I managed to figure out how to manipulate some aspects of the pathfile, but this is an even bigger help. You are the MVP. :)